# Write a request to get offers

Tags: r, url, curl, request

I need to get a list of offers through the path GET/offers/offersByQuery. I have a code to get tokens:

```
url       <- "http://www.somehttp.com"
my_id     <- "my_id"
username  <- "admin"
password  <- "admin"
my_secret <- "k6897pyy-1h7l-11q0-lp10-s20sg4erlq4"

library(httr)

H <- add_headers(`Content-Type`= "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                  `cache-control` = "no-cache")

form_body <- list(grant_type    = "password", 
                  client_id     = my_id,
                  username      = username, 
                  password      = password,
                  client_secret = my_secret)

res <- POST(url = url, body = form_body, encode = "form", H)

content(res, "parsed")
```

But i need to get list of offers. How could i do that? Im really new in curl and requests. Here is an example of requests answers:

```
{"offers":[{id: "BA578JI"],"page":{"size":14,"totalElements":6,"totalPages":6,"number":8}}
```

Comment: That's not legal JSON: `id` is supposed to be quoted, and the json-list `[...]` has an incomplete dictionary (`{"key":"value"}`) with no right-brace `}`.

Comment: But if those are fixed, then `jsonlite::fromJSON(ans)$offers` (assuming `ans` is that json string).

Comment: @r2evans yeah but i want to get that json, not like i have it

Comment: It could be anything. Programmatic APIs into website data is not really standardized (though some may use similar syntax). Without knowing the real url or those who manage it, I don't know how we're supposed to know.